# How to make a dropdownlist using mysql query with foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got a code like this

```
$result1 = mysql_query("select distinct Country  from mtable UNION SELECT DISTINCT MidEstimate FROM mtable");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result1 );

    echo "<select>";
    foreach($row as $vals)
    {
        echo "<option name='$vals'>$vals</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```

The dropdownlist list is showing only one value ? I want the values from both columns in this list please help me to sort this

Comment: One thing to note is that the 2 'DISTINCT' clauses are redundant as the 'UNION' will dedupe your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result1 = mysql_query("select distinct Country  from mtable UNION SELECT DISTINCT MidEstimate FROM mtable");  

echo "<select>";  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo "<option name=\"$row[0]\">$row[0]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result1 = mysql_query("select distinct Country  from mtable UNION SELECT DISTINCT MidEstimate FROM mtable");

echo "<select>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result1 ))
{
    echo "<option name=\"$vals['Country']\">$vals['Country']</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Because you are fecthing your result only once and mysql_fetch_assoc( $result1 ) gets only one row while you want all the rows

Comment: I am combining two columns values in query so that the dropdown list showa values from both coloumns. The above code will display only value from country column ? Is there any way to show both column values in dropdown ?

Comment: what's the difference between my answer and the one from robp except that he is fetching as an array ?

Comment: from your answer it will return only all values from one column in the list while other list all values from both column in list.

Comment: oh yeah ... it won't return any country because obviously it's $row and not $vals :D sorry mate